# Ruby Basic authentication

Tags: ruby, authentication, twitter

I want to build an application that will be making a request to twitter search api using the basic authentication method. In my searches, I came across this following piece of code using rest-client package:

resource = RestClient::Resource.new('http://example.com', :user => 'user', :password => 'password')

however it returned 'bad request: 400'

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter disabled use of basic authentication for their apis nearly 4 years ago. You need to use oauth to make requests on behalf of a user

The twitter api docs on authorization are [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth)

Comment: Thank you for you response fred. I was actually referring to the "application only" authentication mode in Twitter. I assumed that was the same as basic authentication, but i guess that is not the case. I would need to investigate further then.